# CSS - How to color text halfway, progress bar-style?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm trying to style my custom progress bars, but I'm having trouble partially coloring the text when the progress bar is overlapping the text.

Someone else had this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258690/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-color-of-text-halfway-through-a-character-on-a), but I don't like the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6258731/2187401) of having duplicate elements to achieve the effect.

The [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6259054/2187401) doesn't work anymore in modern Webkit browsers, it seems.

Is it possible to do this with only one overlapping element?

HTML:

```
<div class="bar-wrapper">
    <label class="bar-lbl four passed"><span>Q1</span></label>
    <label class="bar-lbl four passed"><span>Q2</span></label>
    <label class="bar-lbl four passed"><span>Q3</span></label>
    <label class="bar-lbl four current"><span>Q4</span></label>

    <div class="bar" data-percent="50"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: FYI: The "other answer" works fine in my Chrome 30.0.1599.101 m

Comment: @h2ooooooo Weird. Are you using Windows? I'm using OS X.

Comment: Yeah - Windows 7 64 bit

Comment: On OS X Mavericks, it won't work in Chrome 30.0.1599.101, or Safari 7. But it does work in Firefox 24 and 25.