# CSS Display One Character in 2 Colors

Tags: html, css, colors, character

Is it possible in css make a single character in 2 colors?

I mean for example character "B" The first upper half in RED and the second half in BLUE

Comment: no, it is not possible, maybe you can try to superimpose two B letters and hide the top half for one, and the bottom half of the second one..

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258690/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-color-of-text-halfway-through-a-character-on-a?rq=1

Answer (score 3):

```
h1 {
  font-size: 72px;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(red 49%, blue 50%);
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

Fill in your own vendor prefixes.

Comment: I don't mean the background! I mean the text color!

Comment: You didn't even try it did you?

Comment: I did: http://jsfiddle.net/LZXTS/1/

Comment: `-webkit-background-clip: text;
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;`

Comment: yeah with chrome works!
with firefox is not

Comment: When I add text-shadow, the entire shadow is visible through the text and it looks bad. Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 2):

One solution would be:

HTML:

```
<span class="half" title="B">B</span>
```

(see that you have to set an attribute value)

CSS:

```
  .half {
        font-size: 90px;
        font-weight: bold;
        position: relative;
        color: blue;
        line-height: 1em;
    }

    .half:before {
        position:absolute;
        content:''attr(title)'';
        color: red;
        height: .5em;
        overflow: hidden;
    }
```

The problem is that every browser calculates the .5em value differently