# Javascript Loadingbar

Tags: javascript, html

I am attempting to create a loading bar in javascript

here is my code:

```
function load(barsize){
    parseInt(barsize);

    var loadingbar = '';
    for(i = 1; i<=barsize;i++){
        loadingbar += '<div style="width:5px; height: 5px; float:left;background-color:green;"></div>'
    }
    document.getElementById('loadingbar').innerHTML = loadingbar;
    if(barsize < 80){
        barsize++;
    timeout = window.setTimeout('load('+barsize+')', 100);
    }
}
```

The debugger is saying "Uncaught ReferenceError: load is not defined" after doing nothing with the statement:

```
timeout = window.setTimeout('load('+barsize+')', 100);
```

Comment: Use `setTimeout(function() { load(barsize); }, 100);`

Comment: @JustinLachapelle There are some working examples here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6258690/is-there-any-way-to-change-the-color-of-text-halfway-through-a-character-on-a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your :

```
timeout = window.setTimeout('load('+barsize+')', 100);
```

with :

```
timeout = window.setTimeout(function() { load(barsize); }, 100);
```

This way you can pass params to the `load` function without getting the `undefined` error

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in this part of the code..

```
timeout = window.setTimeout('load('+barsize+')', 100);
```

Change this to.....

```
timeout = setTimeout(function() { load(barsize); }, 100);
```

Hope this helps..

Glad to help you.

Sangamesh